# strange issue with my keyboard. Some of these keys will not work, and only on cinnamon. Plus help with remapping of a key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, cinnamon

So i tested this on windows as well as with pop!_os (my distro) DE and another DE, and only on cinnamon i'm observing this.

I'm on a german notebook and set up brazilian keyboard layout which, again, in the other contexts is working fine. But on Cinnamon, always one of the following keys will not work byitself, but will when shift is held down: minus/underline, closing square bracket/ closing curly bracket, backslash/vertical bar. As of this moment, it's the last of those which presents this problem. backslash won't appear, but when pressed with shift held down, will give a vertical bar |

I don't know actually if the problem was there from the installation moment or if it began when i started making attempts to remap the last of those keys to slash/question mark, which is a necessity, because my language's layout won't fit in the german keyboard.

I tried using input-remapper, xev, but to no avail.

PC: HP Pavilion 15, pop!_OS 22.04 jammy, Cinnamon version 5.2.7

when i enter xev on terminal then press the key that doesn't work alone (currently the hyphen), this is the output

KeymapNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
keys:  37  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0